# Translating MySQL category tree in multiple languages

Tags: mysql, database

I have an enormous MySQL data table, which contains categories and sub-categories, and now I need a translation of this category tree in other languages.
Table has fields `id | parent_id | title`.

So, what would be the best and the most flexible solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i'm not getting the problem here, but why don't you just add new columns for the new titles in different languages? I suppose the parent_id doesn't need to change so you could simply add the title_en, title_fr etc fields.